# Dialog.setBlurBackgroundRadius() on iOS 6.1.3

Tags: codenameone

on iOS 6.1.3 this code causes a segmentation fault:

```
com.codename1.ui.Dialog.setBlurBackgroundRadius(10.0F);
```

same applies if you modify like this:

```
if (Display.getInstance().isGaussianBlurSupported()) dialog.setBlurBackgroundRadius(10.0F);
```

Only solution I have found is not to use any *setBlurBackgroundRadius()* calls on iOS builds.

Answer (score 0):

My initial gut feeling is that this was related to the old version of iOS but I don't see any code that would cause that. I'll need to pull an old device from storage to test that and I'm not sure my current xcode version would even support that.

There is another possibility and that's out of memory. Blur takes up a lot of memory and if you are already on the edge it might send you over the top. Since this is an old device it might have some memory restrictions that could be triggering that. Either way I'd like to know if this happens on newer devices.

Comment: while trying to figure this issue out I was testing with the xcode device console - and (if memory serves) I think I would have seen memory related warnings there if it was out of memory - but nothing other than the segfault.

Comment: If you have access to xcode can you run this in the debugger and reproduce the crash? This would give you stack traces which would be useful and more detail in the console